# Client side validation for unique field mvc

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I need to implement  unique validation check for my field

```
[Key]
[Required]
[DisplayName("Tag")]
public string Tag { get; set; }
```

Error this Tag Already Exist...

Comment: Where do you want check this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the remote validate rule for this purpose. Add this rule `[Remote("IsTagAvailble", "MyController", ErrorMessage = "Tag Already Exist.")]` to your Tag field. You new code will be

```
[Key]
[Required]
[DisplayName("Tag")]
[Remote("IsTagAvailble", "MyController", ErrorMessage = "Tag Already Exist.")]
public string Tag { get; set; }
```

The first parameter is the Action name and second parameter is your controller name and third parameter is the error text to display to the user.
Now Define this new action in your controller e.g MyController in sample.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult IsTagAvailble(string Tag)
    {
        using (DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var tag = db.TABLE_NAME.Single(m => m.Tag == Tag);
                return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will remotely validate the uniqueness of the Tag filed and display error to the user using unobtrusive javascript.

Finally your view should be something like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tag) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Tag)
```

Comment: Why not to use `return Json(db.TABLE_NAME.Any(m => m.Tag == Tag), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and remove the `try/catch` block? (Not poking you. I just want to know if you had a reason to code this way, like performance or something else.)

Comment: Your suggestion will also work. Its just that both Any() and Single() can raise exceptions. So, just to be a extra safe, I always prefer to use it in a try catch block. Just my style :). I hope your problem has been solved. Right?

Comment: This solution does not work if you are editing an object, but it does work for creating a new object. When editing, It passes the object's "Tag" in this case, to the ActionResult and throws the error to client-side preventing the form submit.